# A question about a speed-controller

Tags: motor-controller

I need to use [this controller](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1394/0900766b81394cac.pdf) with an external applied voltage to control a fan: 
Currently it is controlled manually by a knob. I need to see the internal circuit to interfere.

How can I find the schematics of this product?
Is this a DC to AC converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an SCR-based speed control for induction motors. They work just like a lamp dimmer, delaying the turn-on during each AC half-cycle, except that they use SCRs instead of a triac (because of the inductive load).

The turn-on of the SCRs are typically done by the rising voltage of the AC line charging a cap on each AC cycle, at a rate determined by the speed-pot (also like a lamp dimmer). There is probably nothing inside there that is low voltage.

To control it from an applied voltage, you could replace the pot/cap delay with some other form of delay circuit, but it would need to be able to trigger the SCRs and survive in a 230 volt environment.

Comment: Do you mean the circuit changes the AC amplitude but not the freq?

Comment: please see my related new question thanks: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229730/controlling-a-single-phase-ac-fan-with-a-0-10v-dc-input

Comment: Yes. The line frequency is passed straight through, with the duty-cycle (and therefore the average voltage) determined by when the SCRs fire each half-cycle. I will check your related question now.

Comment: Please see the photos from the circuit here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229730/controlling-a-single-phase-ac-fan-with-a-0-10v-dc-input II understand why there is full wave rectififer. It is not like a typical dimmer circuit. Is this circuit is similar to  http://postimg.org/image/carep5kkx ? Why do you think there is a rectifer?